# Change Row Color Based On Condition In C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi I'm very new to C#. But I have this weblist that print out some result, that I'm trying to change, What I'm trying to do is to make an `if` statement. If row[4] is less then [2] then the row should be red. I have tried to copy some of the code.

```
//##############Print result##############
foreach ( string[] row in dataResult)
{
//Birn.Util.cellDecimalPrinter(row[0],"#,0.0")
//<tr id="PopUp" onclick="OpenWindow('file.aspx?querystr=row[0]&date=textbox.text','500','300')">
%>
<tr>
<td><%=row[0]%></td>
<td><%=row[1]%></td>
<td><%=row[2]%></td>
<td><%=row[3]%></td>
<td><%=row[4]%></td>
</tr>
<%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style of the row using CSS. I have assumed that whatever you are comparing in rows 2 and 4 is a string representation of a Decimal: adjust the `Convert.ToDecimal` to the appropriate type if needed:

```
foreach ( string[] row in dataResult)
{
    string redStyle= "";
    If (Convert.ToDecimal(row[4]) < Convert.ToDecimal(row[2])) {
        // ideally you would have a style defined in a separate CSS file for this
        redStyle = " style=\"background-color: Red; color: White\"";
    }
}
%>
<tr<%=redStyle%>>
<td><%=row[0]%></td>
<td><%=row[1]%></td>
<td><%=row[2]%></td>
<td><%=row[3]%></td>
<td><%=row[4]%></td>
</tr>
<%
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Andrew you are a life saver :) I have been add it for days and when i see the solution its so simple :) but thanks alot

Comment: The trick is to think how you can combine different parts of programming to get the result you want: a little bit of CSS to modify the row, and a bit of C# to apply the CSS as desired. Also, I suggest that you consider using the [Code-Behind Page Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) as it can make it easier to see what is going on: for or a start you can get rid of those eye-watering <% %> constructs.